# Create instances of all classes in a directory with PHP

Tags: php, function, class, directory

I have a directory with several PHP files consisting of classes with the same names as the files. (`Sample.php`'s class will be called `Sample`.)

Each of these classes have a function called `OnCall()`.

How can I create an instance of every class in my directory and execute all of their `OnCall()`s?

I cannot do it manually (`$sample = new Sample(); $sample->OnCall();`, etc etc etc) because more classes will be added, edited and deleted by users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this ought to get the job done:

```
<?php

    foreach (glob('test/class/*.php') as $file)
    {
        require_once $file;

        // get the file name of the current file without the extension
        // which is essentially the class name
        $class = basename($file, '.php');

        if (class_exists($class))
        {
            $obj = new $class;
            $obj->OnCall();
        }
    }
```

Comment: similar to how I would go. I recommend @ suppressing errors on the require, then test for access. Otherwise errors will bring the system to a halt.

Comment: I'm not sure how it could fail to `require` the file, seeing as `glob()` has found it (therefore it must exist).

Comment: Instance of a collision (programmer error).  I have built this pattern  many times and I always include error suppression+check. Just my $0.02 as I agree that ```glob()``` should be solid, php produces "amazing" results sometimes.

Comment: You can remove `require_once` if you're using _composer_ . In addition, there are some PHP functions like `spl_autoload_register()` and `__autoload()` (deprecated as of PHP 7.2.0) [Autoloading Classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php).

Answer (score 12):

This is an old question, but I think [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/class_map_generator.html) is a better solution.

Just by doing:

```
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ClassMapGenerator;

var_dump(ClassMapGenerator::createMap(__DIR__.'/library'));
```

You get:

```
Array
(
    [Acme\Foo] => /var/www/library/foo/Bar.php
    [Acme\Foo\Bar] => /var/www/library/foo/bar/Foo.php
    [Acme\Bar\Baz] => /var/www/library/bar/baz/Boo.php
    [Acme\Bar] => /var/www/library/bar/Foo.php
)
```

(taken from the documentation)

Comment: This is nice - already available in Laravel, and I suppose in Symfony as well ;-)

Comment: Looks like the component has been removed from the latest version of Symfony. Is there another way to get this functionality?

Comment: https://github.com/symfony/class-loader/blob/master/ClassMapGenerator.php

Comment: As of today, you can use it
`\Composer\Autoload\ClassMapGenerator`

Comment: As of today, you can use `Composer\ClassMapGenerator\ClassMapGenerator` with the same semantics.

Answer (score 5):

Since the [Symfony ClassLoader component is deprecated](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-deprecated-the-classloader-component), you can use [`ClassMapGenerator`](https://github.com/composer/class-map-generator/blob/6b90e5568b534f21509d44e12d6eaf72cd098752/src/ClassMapGenerator.php) from Composer.

You need first to add the Composer package with:

```
composer require composer/class-map-generator
```

Then you can use:

```php
$map = ClassMapGenerator::createMap(__DIR__ . '/mydirectory');
```

You will get the related associative table with fully qualified name and file path.

Answer (score 1):

You make a custom loop with in directory and take all required filenames then make something like this.

if $filename = your filename

```
require_once $filename;
$className = basename($filename, ".php");
$class = new $className;
$class->OnCall();
```

Another solution is to store all required filenames in array and then loop its array.

Answer (score 0):

That would be something like

```
public function includeClasses($classes) {
    $tmpMerge = array(
        "classes" => array()
    );
    foreach ($classes as $class) {
        if (file_exists("./Classes/" . $class)) {
            require_once("./Classes/" . $class);
            $classname = explode(".", $class);
            $tmpMerge['classes'][] = $classname[1];
            $this->log->info($this->conf["messages"]["class_includedClassSucessfull"] . $classname[1]);
        } else {
            // File does not exist
        }
    }
    $this->conf = array_merge($tmpMerge, $this->conf);
}
```

I will require that file right in that function, yes and will initialize the class later on.

This function receives an array which looks like that:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "class.setFunctions.php"
  [1]=>
  string(24) "class.renderFrontEnd.php"
  [2]=>
  string(22) "class.getFunctions.php"
}
```

It will add the classnames to a new array which will only contain the class name. And then later on I will iterate through the classnames and initialize the classes.

```
foreach ($this->conf["classes"] as $class) {
                        $this->$class = new $class($this->conf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `spl_autoload_register` that PHP will reference when a new class is declared.

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($className) {
    include 'path/to/your/classes/' . $className . '.php';
});

/**************************/
/* Instantiate your class */

new ClassName();
```

`ClassName` will be passed as a string (all lowercase: "classname") to spl_autoload_register(), so you won't need to `include` or `require` that class file.

See PHP's [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php).

Answer (score -2):

```
foreach (glob('../'.$GO ['name-model'].'/*.php') as $item) 
{
    require_once $item;$className =  ucfirst (basename ($item, '.php'));$class  [$className] =  new $className ();
}
extract($class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your first contribution! :) To make your answer easier to read, please use the [code block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and even add the [syntax highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting) on it!