# PHP, parse all classes of a specific namespace, and list all methods of theses classes

Tags: php, class, oop

I have some classes in a specific directory (by example src/faa/foo) and all theses class have the same namespace (App\faa\foo).

I'm looking to find a proper way for list all methods of theses classes from a php script.

I want do something like this :

```
// list all class of this specific directory
$classes = get_all_class_by_directory_location('src/faa/foo');
// or
$classes = get_all_class_by_namespace('App\foo\faa');
    // but that means I must include theses classes to my script isn't it ? I think it's an ugly way because I only need print methods name, I don't need use them in this script 

foreach($classes as $class){
    print(get_methods($class));
}
```

What is the best approach for do what I want ? Does it exist a maintained community php package for do that ?

My project follow the psr-4 convention, maybe this information is usefull..

Comment: use the Reflection API: http://php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php

foreach (glob('src/faa/foo/*.php') as $file)
{
    require_once $file;

    // get the file name of the current file without the extension
    // which is essentially the class name
    $class = basename($file, '.php');

    if (class_exists($class))
    {
        $obj = new $class;
        foreach(get_class_methods($obj) as $method)
        {
          echo $method . '\n';
        }
    }
}
```

Taken from: [Create instances of all classes in a directory with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21559957/create-instances-of-all-classes-in-a-directory-with-php) then added get_class_methods usage.